# Error 'Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin' while using $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json

I am using jquery `$.getJSON` and keep getting the following error.

> Origin http://example.co.uk is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

The issue i am having is it was working fine then suddenly started to do this any reason why this might happen here is my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/isimpledesign/KnUBH/

Comment: is it a cross-domain request? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760993/jquery-getjson-cross-domain-problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error when you try to make a request from your site to a site on a different domain (or sub-domain). It is possible to configure the other site to allow you to make requests ([see Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control)), although this feature is not supported everywhere.

An alternative to normal AJAX calls is JSONP, which requires the server to support it but doesn't have cross-domain restrictions. It turns out that Blogger does support this, so you just need to modify the URL to

```
var url = 'http://isimpledesign.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json&callback=?'
```

and jQuery will handle it properly. ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KnUBH/2/))

Comment: I am making a request to blogger is this a bad way to work, will i have trouble with support seems to be working fine.

Comment: @user658500: It turns out that blogger has a simple way to make this work, I've edited my post.