# couldn't display json multiple objects with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new with Jquery. but, I want to get Json multiple objects then append it into html element.
here my first jquery code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://epomia.com/tmp/dc.php", function(data){
        $.each(data, function(id, vall){
            $.each(vall, function(x, y){
                $("#mbuh").append(y);
            });
        });

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mbuh">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but, why doesn't want to display json data ?
which are wrong ? the json in http://epomia.com/tmp/dc.php or my code ?

Comment: May be it's a cross domain issue. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008879/error-origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin-while-using-getjs

Comment: thanks bro, my json file indeed outside from my host.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is correct.

The JSON from the link you provided is an object with 4 properties each of which is an array. 
You don't have to iterate through that Array in order to append each element. You can simply call

```
$.each(data, function (id, vall) {
    $("#mbuh").append(vall);
});
```

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mZ4vv/)