# jQuery get returns error

Tags: ajax, jquery

Why does this simple ajax show an alert with "error"?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
    $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.google.com", 
                success: function(data) { alert(data); }, 
                error: function(req, err) { alert(err);}
         });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Probably a problem with cross-domain requests. Look it up, there are many posts and questions online about this subject.

Comment: @Styxxy. without "probably" :)

Comment: True, but you know theoretically there might be another issue; but seeing this code it is almost certain cross-domain issues :P.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly do this with javascript but there are alternative ways to do it if you are using a server.

javascript part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $.ajax({
             url: "http://yourserver/geturl.php?url=http://www.google.com",
             // or url: "http://yourserver/geturl.aspx?url=http://www.google.com",
             success: function(data) {
                 alert(data);    
             }, 
             error: function(req, err) {
                 alert(err);
             }
         });
    }); 
 </script>
```

the server part (for **geturl.php**):

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents($_GET["url"]);
?>
```

or the same logic with asp.net.

**the key part is here, that the code runs the javascript and php(aspx) should be on the same domain.**

Comment: Thanks, what about getJSON? Should i be able to get data from any domain if i add "callback=?" to the url?

Comment: This question is answered more detailed here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760993/jquery-getjson-cross-domain-problems