# http://api.easyjquery.com/ips/ didn't retern value

Tags: jquery, json

HTML:

```
<div class=iplookup>23.25.49.250</div>;
<div class=iplookup>188.2.50.62</div>;
```

jQuery:

```
$("div").mouseup(function () {
    IP = $(this).text();
    $.getJSON("http://api.easyjquery.com/ips/", {
        IP: IP
    }, function (data) {
        alert("XXX");
        alert(data.continentName + "\n" + data.countryName + " " + data.cityName);
        $(this).append("=" + data.countryName + "," + data.cityName);

    });

});
```

What is wrong with this code? Why isn't the `alert()` shown?

Comment: Nik could have a valid point with his answer. But other potential problems could be so much as there is no return data, the data returned isn't valid JSON (might be a string). Other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service is not returning JSONP, which you need for cross domain calls.  See  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760993/jquery-getjson-cross-domain-problems) for similar issue.