# Get JSON data and put it into HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to solve a issue regarding to JSON data (getting and post it). Bellow I posted my code which doesn't work and I don't know why? I checked with Firebug and says that it's ok: `200 OK sourceforge.net 1.4 KB 216.34.181.60:80`

What I'm trying to do, is to get some stats from a sourceforge project and put it into a div tag.

The link is a valid json (`http://sourceforge.net/projects/rdss/files/stats/json?start_date=2010-12-01&end_date=2012-11-24`).

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $.getJSON("http://sourceforge.net/projects/rdss/files/stats/json?start_date=2010-12-01&end_date=2012-11-24", function(data) {
            $.each(data.posts, function(i,data) {
              var div_data = "<div>"+data.oses+"</div>";
              $(div_data).appendTo("#testjson");
            });
          });
          return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
    <div id="testjson"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Apparently, `oses` is an array of arrays and there's no `posts` property.

Comment: Best to start by dumping the object to your console to explore its contents:  `console.log(data)` inside the `getJSON()` callback

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760993/jquery-getjson-cross-domain-problems

Comment: `$(function() {` and `$(document).ready(function() {` are redundant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778

Answer (score 1):

This is a cross domain issue. Check the console. You need write a proxy at the server side to get around. Based on your server side language, you can Google a proxy snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a cross-browser request: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy.

So, `getJSON` is failing and trowing exception.. see ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101)

When this happens you can workaround [using CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696).

But for this workaround work, you [need server be CORS-enabled](http://enable-cors.org/server.html), what unfortunately sourceforge isn't.

You can see this by checking response header. It has the key `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`.

Usually, you can do this by accessing Developer Tools in Browsers:
- Select Network tab.
- Identify JSON page and select.
- Open Header tab
- Go to Response Headers section.

See an example:

[image]