# $.getJSON does not work

Tags: jquery

What am I doing wrong? Following does not upate my json object:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

```
function getJson() {
    $.getJSON("http://laptop/EstimatorWeb/GetConfig.ashx", function (da) {
        json = da;
        //document.getElementById("resDiv").innerText=da;
    }).success(function () {
        alert("second success");
    }).error(function () {
        alert("error");
    });
```

I can see my web services returning a JSON object in FIddler. It is just this last piece that is not updating the object. I do not receive any alert either for success or for error.

Comment: change `http://laptop/EstimatorWeb/GetConfig.ashx` to valid url

Comment: @TamilSelvan: Did you try to follow that URL?

Comment: `http://laptop/EstimatorWeb...` doesn't look like a valid URL.

Comment: `success` and `error` are `$.ajax()` option properties. You're looking for `done` and `fail`. Why is the line that sets the `innerText` commented? Of course this snippet won't update anything. You could try doing `console.log(da)` in your success callback to make sure it looks ok.

Comment: try hitting this url http://laptop/EstimatorWeb/GetConfig.ashx, does it have a json response?

Comment: @FelixKling he said he's getting a response in fiddler. I assume `laptop` is the name of a computer on his local network.

Comment: @JasonP: Mmh, that makes sense.

Comment: I just saw a similar thing happening and it turned out to be a cross domain problem. Is your page served from "laptop"? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760993/jquery-getjson-cross-domain-problems for possible solutions.

Comment: Both HTML page and web service are running on the same machine. Service does generate JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use .done() and .fail(), .success() and .error() were [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/?.gutter) in v1.8 
[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/VWUju/)

```
$.getJSON("http://laptop/EstimatorWeb/GetConfig.ashx", function(json){
        $("#resDiv").text(json);  
     }).done(function(data){
         alert('second done' + data.Host);
     }).fail(function(e){
         alert('fail');
     });
```

you will just need to convert the json to string

Comment: Tried this and still does not get anything...URL is a .NET web service and returns a json object which i tested using browser. Issue is with this function only in JavaScript. Not sure what is wrong since I am very new to JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: @ybittu if you remove the alert from done and add one instead of  $("#resDiv").text(json); do you get the alert?